# Can I opt that my app support up to iOS 8.4?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I have submitted app and it got rejected as it crashed in iOS 9 devices. Can I opt out for iOS9 like I will say my app will support up to iOS 8.4. I don't want to support iOS 9?

Comment: Just a suggestion: most probably, it is not possible. Why should Apple support an outdated application? Why don't you just write your application so that it will work on all iOS versions?

Comment: As its not publicly available and supporting it would require Xcode 7 which is also not available through the app store. How would some one support it?

Comment: you can get xcode 7 beta through the [apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)

Comment: Apple have announced that they will now accept apps built with the GM release of Xcode 7 and targeting iOS9.  Regardless of which toolset you use to build the app, it is expected that it will work on iOS9.  Apple user's tend to upgrade their devices soon after new releases and expect apps to keep working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not opt out of the current (or about to be released) iOS version.  Apple will test iOS app submissions to their App store on the iOS version currently running on the devices that its customers are currently buying or will soon be buying just days from now.  And that's currently iOS 9.0.  Why put an app in the store that will crash a couple days after a customer buys it just before upgrading their device?

Also, most apps built with the SDK for the previous iOS version should work on devices running the next iOS version, perhaps after testing (and tweaking API usage) on devices running a beta version of that next iOS version, which is available to all enrolled developers.  This testing does require Xcode 7 (although using the Xcode-beta or GM makes some of the testing and debugging a lot easier).  There are other ways to put a test app on your test device, such as Ad Hoc deployment via iTunes.